Difficulty adding page numbers to printed table using Paged.js without content overflow
I have a table with numerous  elements in its , and I'm attempting to add page numbers to each printed page using Paged.js. However, I'm encountering issues where the table content overflows the page or the layout doesn't respect margins properly when using Paged.js.
